# opencv SVM One_Class not working

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning, svm, feature-detection

I've [**read**](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/how-to-detect-the-exception-by-svm-with-opencv) [about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416522/what-is-the-opencv-svm-type-parameter) [**using**](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/support_vector_machines.html#cvsvmparams-cvsvmparams) `ONE_CLASS SVMs` to do multi-class classification, but so far I have been unable to get one working.

I am testing the `SVM` against the exact same images it is trained with, so it should have a 100% correctness rate (which I managed with `C_SVC` & `NU_SVC`). Im following the same process as I did for `C_SVC` & `NU_SVC` (with params changed, and using only positive inputs obviously) and it isn't working. I've changed the Images, FeatureDetectors, DescriptorExtractors, and DescriptorMatchers but still no luck.

It will (depending on various changes i.e. image sizes, dictionary size etc) throw out some 1's, though they are rarely correct.

**Detection:**

```
Ptr<FeatureDetector>        detector    (new OrbFeatureDetector());
Ptr<DescriptorExtractor>    extractor   (new SurfDescriptorExtractor());
Ptr<DescriptorMatcher>      matcher     (new BruteForceMatcher<L2<float>>());
BOWImgDescriptorExtractor   bowDE       (extractor, matcher);
```

**BOWKMeansTrainer Params:**

```
int dictionarySize  = 1000;
TermCriteria termCrit(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 100, 0.001);
int retries         = 3;
int flags           = KMEANS_PP_CENTERS;    
BOWKMeansTrainer bowTrainer(dictionarySize, termCrit, retries, flags);
```

**OLD SVM Params:**

```
params.kernel_type  = CvSVM::LINEAR;
params.svm_type     = CvSVM::ONE_CLASS;
params.nu           = 0.0001;
params.term_crit    = TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 500, 1e-6);
```

**NEW SVM Params:**

```
params.kernel_type  = CvSVM::RBF;
params.svm_type     = CvSVM::ONE_CLASS;
params.nu           = 0.0000009;
params.degree       = 2;
params.gamma        = 1;
params.term_crit    = TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER+CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 1000, FLT_EPSILON);
```

I have no clue as to why it wont work, especially on the images used to train it.

Comment: Maybe the linear kernel doesn't fit to your problem. Have you tried with an other one?

Comment: I was initially using `POLY`, but as `LINEAR` was the one chosen in the first page I linked where the person had shared their functioning `ONE_CLASS SVM` I tried it, but again to no avail. -- `LINEAR` `POLY` & `RBF` all show different outputs when it comes to prediction, but not until the output is 1 for all the images used for training will the `SVM` be properly functioning.

Comment: What is the accuracy score? It is not true that if you test on the training set you'll always get 100% score, it depends on regularization parameters and on the distribution of data. So it can happen that different classifier achieve different performance

Comment: But surely that is an issue, if an `SVM` says that an image it is trained with as a positive isn't positive? It doesn't make sense for it to be told that an image is positive, and then upon viewing the same image again, saying that it isn't.